# Service does not start when the phone is started

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-permissions

I'm pretty new to android programming. I'm trying to start a service when the phone is started but it does not work. I've already seen other question done by other users but no one worked till now. This is my broadcast receiver.

```
public class StartBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
            context.startService(intent1);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".StartBoot">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>
```

In the log i read this

```
W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x9000010 (has extras) } to com.google.android.apps.docs/.app.NotificationChannelReceiver requires android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED due to sender null (uid 1000)
```

Thank you in advance for the answers

Comment: You need to add the BOOT permission in the manifest

Comment: I added it but i forgot to add it here in the request, now i've corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

from the `<intent-filter>` inside `<receiver>` tag. This category is only needed for `<intent-filter>` inside of `<activity>` declaration. For a `<receiver>` you only need the ACTION.

The error message you posted has nothing to do with your application, it is complaining about another application.